# Removing characters using preg_replace function

Tags: php, preg-replace

I use preg_replace function. I want the function not to remove apostrophe (**'**) character. So I want it to return the word as (o'clock) .
How can I do that?

```
$last_word = "o'clock.";

$new_word= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/','',$last_word);

echo $new_word;
```

Comment: then include and escaped apostrophe in the list of characters you are ignoring.

Comment: So what should the end result be? What's the rule you're looking for (in English)? Is it, "remove any character that is not a letter, number, space, or apostrophe"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$last_word = "o'clock.";
$new_word= preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9\' ]/','',$last_word);
echo $new_word;
```

Demo here: http://ideone.com/JMH8F

Answer (score 0):

That regex explicitly removes all characters *except* for letters and numbers. Note the leading "^". So it does what you ask it to.

So most likely you want to add the "'" (apostrophe) to the exclusion set inside the regex:

```
'/[^a-zA-Z0-9\' ]/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your original `'/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/'` to `"/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ']/"`.  This simply includes the apostrophe in the negated character class.

See an [online example](http://so.viperpad.com/GQkjyn).

<sup>Aside: my suggestion would be to use double-quotes for the string (as you have with `"o'clock."`) since mixing backslash escapes with PHP strings and regex patterns can get confusing quickly.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It may help..

```
$new_word= preg_replace('/\'/', '', $last_word);
```

Demo: http://so.viperpad.com/F82z9o

Answer (score -1):

That regex you use does not remove the "'" (apostrophe). Instead it does not match the subject string at all because of the "." (dot). In that case preg_replace() returns NULL.

Comment: Is there away to return (o'clock) ?